# I’m a foreigner with an expired passport which has my valid visa. Can I take a domestic flight in the US if I don’t have any other ID?

Tags: usa, passports, domestic-travel, expired

I’m travelling from Rochester to Boston. My passport has expired and I do not have any state ID. Can I still travel with the expired passport but valid visa?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm a foreigner, can I fly inside USA with my USA visa if my passport expires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22038/im-a-foreigner-can-i-fly-inside-usa-with-my-usa-visa-if-my-passport-expires)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I fly domestically in the US using my university ID?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17811/can-i-fly-domestically-in-the-us-using-my-university-id). This OP had an expired non-US passport with a valid US visa.

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but are you sure you are in status? I-94 granted at entry will not have a date that is past passport expiration. So unless your I-94 has "D/S" (common for F or J statuses) or you got Change of Status or Extension of Stay, your I-94 is probably expired.

Answer (score 18):

The TSA has [repeatedly](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2018/08/02/four-tips-remember-when-checking-your-id-airport-security) [stated](https://twitter.com/asktsa/status/981521539844726784) that an expired passport is considered valid ID as long as it expired less than one year ago.

Even if your passport was beyond this limit, it's still possible to fly if the TSA officers are able to confirm your identity. Whilst a US Visa is not an valid identification document in it's own right, in conjunction with your expired passport and potentially other ID you have it would almost certainly be sufficient for the TSA officers to suitably confirm your identity.  See [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17811/can-i-fly-domestically-in-the-us-using-my-university-id) for some further details (That question is almost a duplicate of this one, except that it doesn't mention how long ago the expiry occurred which makes the situation/answer a little different)

Answer (score 0):

According to both United and Delta airlines websites, it is required to have a *valid unexpired* document to travel within the US:

From Delta [(within U.S page)](https://www.delta.com/us/en/check-in-security/required-travel-documents/travel-within-the-us#:%7E:text=In%20the%20United%20States%2C%20you,your%20unexpired%20government%2Dissued%20ID.):

> In the United States, you need a valid U.S. government-issued photo ID or a passport from your country of origin to travel through security. You must show that the name on your boarding pass matches the legal name on your **unexpired** government-issued ID.

and from United website [(U.S. territory travel document requirements)](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/id/travel.html):

> Travelers 18 years of age or older are required to have a valid, current U.S. federal or state-issued photo ID that contains name, date of birth, gender, expiration date and a tamper-resistant feature for travel to or from a U.S. Territory (Guam, Puerto Rico and U.S. Virgin Islands). **Expired documents are not accepted**. The following IDs are accepted:
>
> - ........
> - A foreign government-issued passport
> - ........

Comment: From your second link, "Travelers who don’t present an acceptable ID may be subject to additional screening." - this would suggest that it might be possible with other forms of ID - potentially the valid US Visa would be acceptable.

Comment: The second paragraph seems to mean that you can't fly to Guam, Puerto Rico or US Virgin Islands with your expired passport. And the first seems to mean that US citizens cannot travel with an expired government-issued ID. Your foreign passport wouldn't be an "expired government-issued ID".

Comment: In the Delta paragraph, the word "valid" only applies to "U.S. government-issued photo ID," which is alternative to "a passport from your country of origin." Thus when it later on says "unexpired government-issued ID" I would understand that as implicitly not being a requirement of the alternative passport option, though altogether that paragraph is very ambiguously worded, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: So you guys suggesting that airlines inside the US are spreading the wrong info for their passengers?

Comment: I think they are saying you made a mistake in interpreting what Delta is saying.

Comment: Delta and other airlines don't check IDs on domestic flights, only the TSA does, so their opinion on the subject is pretty much moot.

Comment: @NeanDerThal Well, Delta is certainly providing _contradictory_ information to their passengers. The section about travel to US territories plainly states in the opening paragraph that adult travellers must have a “valid, current U.S. federal or state-issued photo ID”, which completely excludes any foreigners (unless they happen to have such US-issued photo ID). Then immediately afterwards, they list non-US passports as valid documentation, in direct contradiction to their first claim.

Comment: "you guys suggesting that airlines inside the US are spreading the wrong info for their passengers?": My impression is that correct information about such requirements is the exception rather than the rule.